# Error with using ng-repeat over object literal in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular js and I am practicing now filter. I am perfectly able to iterate over array of objects  but when I am using object of objects my browser throws error :
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="myCont">

                <div ng-repeat="b in ar2">
                    {{b}}
                </div>

                {{a}}
                </br></br>
                {{c | myFilt}}
                </br>
                </br>
                <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in d">
                    {{key.a|myFilt}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular_try.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the angular js :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[])

myApp.controller("myCont",["$scope","$filter",function($scope,$filter){
$scope.a ="pro";
$scope.arr = ["abc","bcd","cdb"];
$scope.arr3 = [100,200,300];
$scope.ar2=[];
$scope.c = 10;
$scope.d = {{a:"mishtu",b:500,c:"mondal"},{a:"tulu",b:400,c:"mondal"},
{a:"titlu",b:600,"c":"mondal"}}
}])
```

Comment: `$scope.d = [{a:"mishtu",b:500,c:"mondal"},{a:"tulu",b:400,c:"mondal"},
{a:"titlu",b:600,"c":"mondal"}];`

Comment: `{{value.a|myFilt}}`

Comment: @Punit JSFiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr8jtt0z/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not my question I know we can iterate over array of objects but I want to iterate over object of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object contains value always in (key,value) pair but your object

```
$scope.d = {{a:"mishtu",b:500,c:"mondal"},{a:"tulu",b:400,c:"mondal"},
{a:"titlu",b:600,"c":"mondal"}}
```

is holding a list of objects, so you should have declared it as an array.
Like this

```
$scope.d = [{a:"mishtu",b:500,c:"mondal"},{a:"tulu",b:400,c:"mondal"},
{a:"titlu",b:600,"c":"mondal"}]
```

**This is how it should be used**:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Hello world';

  $scope.d = [{
    a: "mishtu",
    b: 500,
    c: "mondal"
  }, {
    a: "tulu",
    b: 400,
    c: "mondal"
  }, {
    a: "titlu",
    b: 600,
    "c": "mondal"
  }];

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div>{{title}}</div>

  <table border="1" ng-repeat="myObj in d">
    <tr ng-repeat="(x, y) in myObj">
      <td>{{x}}</td>
      <td>{{y}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```